# CheckBox onClick is not working in react type-script

Tags: reactjs, typescript, checkbox, react-typescript

I have designed a component MyCheckBox ( i used it as helper component ), so I imported it in another component, but whenever i am trying to trigger the event, it not triggered.

Code for reference

MyCheck Box

```
    interface MyCheckBoxProps
    {
     onClick?:MouseEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>;
     checked?:boolean
    }
    
    export const MyCheckBox (props:MyCheckBoxProps): JSX.Element =>{
    return(
              <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  id={id}
                  onClick={onClick}
                  checked={checked}
                />
          )  
    }
```

When I Imported it

```
const[check,setCheck] = useState(false)

  const handleCheckChange = (e: any, key: string) => {
    console.log("check", e)  // => this console log does not show up
    if (key === "newPostActivity") {
      console.log("check", e)
    setCheck(e.target.checked)
    }
  }
  <MyCheckBox checked={check} onClick={(e)=>handleCheckChange(e,"some string")}/>
```

Whenever I click on MyCheckBox , the event ( handleCheckChange )is never triggered

Anybody please help?

Comment: You are calling: `handleCheck` not `handleCheckChange`

Comment: Hi, please check the edit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't understand if you wrote this code as an example of a not working one. If this is the final code, you must destruct the props to use like that.

```
          <input
              type="checkbox"
              id={id}
              onClick={onClick}
              checked={checked}
            />
```

Otherwise, you should call:

```
          <input
              type="checkbox"
              id={props.id}
              onClick={props.onClick}
              checked={props.checked}
            />
```

I've rewrote your code:

App

```
export default function App() {
  const [check, setCheck] = useState(false);
  const handleCheckChange = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>, key: string) => {
    console.log("check", e);
    setCheck(!check);
    console.log("I am state", check);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <MyCheckBox
        id="foo"
        checked={check}
        onClick={(e) => handleCheckChange(e, "some string")}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

MyCheckBox

```
interface MyCheckBoxProps {
  id: string;
  onClick?: MouseEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>;
  checked?: boolean;
}
const MyCheckBox: React.FC<MyCheckBoxProps> = (props) => {
  const { id, onClick, checked } = props;
  return <input type="checkbox" id={id} onClick={onClick} checked={checked} />;
};

export default MyCheckBox;
```

Copied from my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-dawn-cuu6k)

Comment: I wrote as an example, due to copyright issues, dude i already destructed it, but was not mentioned in the above, code i am having issue with the typescript code

Comment: The problem is in the `MouseEvents`?

Comment: Yes man, i am unable to provide proper arguments for the mouse event

Comment: @Thanks Vinicus, appreciated for the help man. I already tried, this I am facing this error "MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement, MouseEvent>' provides no match for the signature '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement, MouseEvent>): void'."

Comment: Check my codesandbox, there is no issues: https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-dawn-cuu6k?file=/src/MyCheckBox.tsx:51-376

Comment: Could explain better your problem in the question above, so it could help others, mark as answered as well.

Comment: sure brother !@Vinicius

Answer (score 0):

you are calling

```
<MyComponent checked={check}
        onClick={(e) => handleCheckChange(e, "some string")}/>
```

in your App component which is the parent component. Here your checked and onclick are the props. so now accessing the props in your <MyComponent you have to make sure to call it as

```
   import React from "react";
    export default function MyCheckBox(props) {
      return (
        <input type="checkbox" onClick={props.onClick} checked={props.checked} />
      );
    }
```

OR

destructrize your props like

```
   import React from "react";
    export default function MyCheckBox({onClick, checked}) {
      return (
        <input type="checkbox" onClick={onClick} checked={checked} />
      );
    }
```

Comment: if this resolved your issue, can you please accept or upvote :)

Comment: No it did not , and moreover I do not  have reputation to upvote someone answer, I am sorry ,